# How does BigInteger interpret the bytes from a string?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, utf-8, biginteger

Im working on a program that is an implementation of the RSA encryption algorithm, just as a personal exercise, its not guarding anyone's information or anything. I am trying to understand how a plaintext passage is being interpreted numerically, allowing it to be encrypted. I understand that most UTF-8 characters end up only using 1 byte of space, and not the 2 bytes one might think, but thats about it. Heres my code:

```
BigInteger ONE = new BigInteger("1");
   SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

   BigInteger d, e, n;
   BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, rand);
   BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, rand);
   BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(ONE));

   n = p.multiply(q);
   e = new BigInteger("65537");
   d = e.modInverse(phi);

   String string = "test";
   BigInteger plainText = new BigInteger(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   BigInteger cipherText = plainText.modPow(e, n);
   BigInteger originalMessage = cipherText.modPow(d, n);
   String decrypted = new String(originalMessage.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");

   System.out.println("original: " + string);
   System.out.println("decrypted: " + decrypted);
   System.out.println(plainText);
   System.out.println(cipherText);
   System.out.println(originalMessage);
   System.out.println(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));

   byte byteArray[] = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

   for(byte littleByte:byteArray){
       System.out.println(littleByte);
   }
```

It outputs:

```
original: test
decrypted: test
1952805748
16521882695662254558772281277528769227027759103787217998376216650996467552436
1952805748
[B@60d70b42
116
101
115
116
```

Maybe more specifically i am wondering about this line:

`BigInteger plainText = new BigInteger(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Does each letter of "test" have a value, and they are literraly added together here? Like say t=1,e=2,s=3,t=1 for example, if you get the bytes from that string, do you end up with 7 or are the values just put together like 1231? And why does

`BigInteger plainText = new BigInteger(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));` output `1952805748`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to understand how a plaintext passage is being interpreted numerically, allowing it to be encrypted.

It really boils down to understanding what this line does:

```
   BigInteger plainText = new BigInteger(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Lets break it down.

1. We start with a String (`string`).  A Java string is a sequence of characters represented as Unicode code points (encoded in UCS-16 ...).
2. The `getBytes("UTF-8")` then encodes the characters as a sequence of bytes, and returns them in a newly allocated byte array.
3. The `BigInteger(byte[])` constructor interprets that byte array as a number.  As the javadoc says:

   > Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is
   >   assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is
   >   in the zeroth element.

The method that is being used here is not giving an intrisically meaningful number, just one that corresponds to the byte-encoded string.  And going from the byte array to the number is simply treating the bytes as a bit sequence that represents an integer in 2's complement form ... which is the most common representation for integers on modern hardware.

The key thing is that the transformation from the text to the (unencrypted) BigInteger is lossless and reversible.  Any other transformation with those properties could be used.

References:

- The Wikipedia page on [2's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation
- The Wikipedia page on the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) text encoding scheme
- javadoc [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29)
- javadoc [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29)

---

> Im still not quite understanding how the the UTF-8 values for each character in "test", 116,101,115,116 respectively come together to form 1952805748?

1. Convert the numbers 116,101,115,116 to hex.
2. Convert the number 1952805748 to hex
3. Compare them

See the pattern?

Comment: Im still not quite understanding how the the UTF-8 values for each character in "test", 116,101,115,116 respectively come together to form 1952805748?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the output, "test" is encoded into array of 4 bytes [116, 101, 115, 116]. This is then interperted by BigInteger as binary integer representation. The value can be calculated this way

```
value = (116 << 24) + (101 << 16) + (115 << 8) + 116;
```

Comment: What are these values? And why does 

`BigInteger plainText = new BigInteger(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));` output `1952805748`

Comment: How do those values come together to produce 1952805748?

Comment: Okay, so i read UTF-8 acts as ASCII for the first 127 characters, that makes sense the t=116=01110100 part. But (116 << 24) + (101 << 16) ... , where do you get the 24,16,8,0? So 116 << 24 in binary is 01110100 << 11000, what does the shift operator mean in this context addition?

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit more, how do you come up with that calculation?

Comment: Binary representation of 1952805748 = 0x74657374, it's 4 bytes, in decimal format it's 116, 101, 115, 116